# AutoMapper add custom property that does not exist in source but has to exist in target

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got a simple ASP.NET Core controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
public ActionResult<RequestDto> Get(int id, [FromQuery]GetRequest getRequest)
{
    var query = Mapper.Map<GetRequest, FindRequestQuery>(getRequest);
    query.Id = id;

    var request = _requestService.Find(query);

    if (request == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var requestDto = Mapper.Map<Request, RequestDto>(request);

    return Ok(requestDto);
}
```

My `GetRequest` does not have Id property, however my `FindRequestQuery` has one.

The example above works just fine, but I'm interested to know if there's a way to tell AutoMapper to map id from method parameter to FindRequestQuery property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Custom Value Resolvers](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)?

Comment: I have not, will check this out!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the capability provided by AutoMapper's [Inline Mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html) functionality.

Specifically, it will look something like this

```
var query = Mapper.Map<GetRequest, FindRequestQuery>(
                    getRequest, 
                    opt => opt.ConfigureMap().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, m => m.MapFrom(src => id)));
```

Comment: I'll check this one out as well. Thank you!

Comment: Inline(Dynamic) mapping removed as of Automapper V9
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3063